# Closing socket cause TIME_WAIT pending state

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, state

I'm facing off with some issues using socket client/server.

In my socket flow, I close on server side after I send the response:

```
private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    try
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }
    catch { }
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        //handler.Dispose();
        handler.Close();



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

on client side, I call the close socket function after I read the answer from server:

```
var cc = new AsynchronousClient("192.168.1.201", 11001);
var er = cc.echo();
cc.closeConn();

public void closeConn(){
    sc.Close();
}

public void Close()
{
    if (socket != null && IsConnected)
    {
        OnClosed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        IsConnected = false;

        socket.Close();
        socket = null;
    }
}
```

After the call are called both on server and client side, using TCPView, I can see the ports are in the state TIME_WAIT. I tried other solutions, like using methods as Dispose, Disconnect and other fast solution, but nothing seems to force the closing of the connection and free the port as the commucation ends.

Looking this image, I can see that TIME_WAIT is the last state before the real closing of the socket.

I tried also, for example, to close the connection only server side. What I get is the client blocked on the CLOSE_WAIT state and the server on FIN_WAIT2 state. So, a step before the TIME_WAIT.

In some way, I think, I have to send the last ACK to pass from TIME_WAIT to CLOSED. How can I reach my goal?

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I tried this on my server side:

```
var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);
```

Comment: What's your goal ? avoid `TIME_WAIT` ? no, you can't. Use `so_reuseaddr` to minimize its effect.

Comment: @ZangMingJie Yes my goal is avoid TIME_WAIT.. I can't?Look the update, I tried the reuseaddress option, but I didn't notice any changes. Maybe didi I set it in the wrong way?

Comment: is `TIME_WAIT` causing any issue ? if not, who cares. You can not avoid it, just ignore it.

Comment: is causing issue when I receive tons of requests and I have to wait the end of TIME_WAIT before to receive new requests... I see some tools closing connections without passing from TIME_WAIT state, how do they do this?

Comment: Found the solution, look the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is use the Windows API.

Here the code:

```
[DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int closesocket(IntPtr s);
```

And the call is

```
closesocket(socket.Handle);
```

I call this only on one side, not both. After a long analisys with TCPView I can say it works as expected.